# Purpose of ref parameter to web service

Tags: web-services, ref

Okay, I've got some sample code that I'm supposed to be going through to use an example for how to use a product...and I've got this code:

```
protected void checkout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OurWebServiceClient client = new OurWebServiceClient();
    this.session = client.BindAccount(ref this.session);
    client.FinalizeSession(this.session);
    client.Close();
    this.checkout.Text = "success";
    this.checkout.Enabled = false;
}
```

So this code is a bit strange to me for various reasons, but the line that stands out to me is the second line in the method:

```
this.session = client.BindAccount(ref this.session);
```

It's a ref, so this.session could actually point to a different object after the call.  Except then they assign this.session to the value returned from the call, blowing away (as far as I can tell) anything they gained by having it as a ref.  And what does it mean to have a ref variable passed into a web service anyway?

Comment: +1 this is indeed perplexing and if it does have use, certainly makes for confusing code. But I actually came to up vote you for a genius comment on a now-locked question about technobabble. :)

Comment: @ElRonnoco Okay, so now I'm curious...what was it?

Comment: It's your comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/175692/395628)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever returned by that web service will be assigned to `this.session`. The usage of ref is lost since `this.session` is assigned back to the returned value.

By passing a parameter as ref to a web service, you get the funationality you'd expect from any other method call ie your changes on that parameter are reflected back. But IMO this is not a good practice to code web services. It's confusing.